# Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore... shows this error while running the app

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've added AWSCore & AWSS3 frameworks for file upload to amazon s3. While running the app on mobile.It shows this error message on the log  I'm not using cocoapods. Please help.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/63776E2B-E41E-4CCF-A3B2-F19181749296/appname.app/appname
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: are you added your framework in embed binaries

Comment: I added it in Link binary with libraries. (xcode 9). still not working.

Comment: are you seen this add your library in `embed binaries ` also

Comment: I added it in embedded binaries. now it is working .Thank you.

Comment: welcome bro....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these frameworks in the `Embed Binaries` section of your project settings for them to be loaded into your app.

Comment: I added it in Link binary with libraries. (xcode 9). still not working.

Comment: I added it in embedded binaries. now it is working.Thank you